# Creating a Visual Studios 2010 ASP.NET application without a Masterpage

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I've spent a decent amount of time on the web and messing around in the settings and I haven't been able to find a way to create a project in VWD 2010 without a masterpage. Just removing the reference yields an error.

Anyone know where I can find some information on this? I'm creating a simple application that has no use for a masterpage.

Comment: Delete the masterpage, delete the default page and create a new page... that should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, just create an "Empty ASP.NET Web Application", then add your pages as you see fit.